# ASP net MVC is it possible to assign custom values to the ID key for members of a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add elements to a database in Asp.net MVC but I want to assign the elements I add to it a custom value for its ID (the database key). The reason is I am creating two databases that function together. Database A has items in it, and I want database B to use the ID from database A to access items that Database B has listed that are grouped by dbA's ID.

For example if Object 1 in DbA is an object that represents a test/quiz with Id 1, I want DbB to have items stored in it (questions) with IDs starting from ID = 1000 going all the way up to ID = 1999. starting at ID= 1000, then 1001, 1002, etc. So space for about 999 question objects before the next test object's questions start at 2000, 2001, etc.

```
public class Question
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }
        public string MultipleChoiceCorrect { get; set; }
        public string MultipleChoiceB { get; set; }
        public string MultipleChoiceC { get; set; }
        public string MultipleChoiceD { get; set; }
}
```

*Why I'm trying this convoluted way:* Originally I tried storing the information I would have in DbB as a list attribute for the objects in DbA, but my knowledge of of Databases just wasn't sufficient to get this to work because the list attribute would never save to the database and I've since given up on this method.

So my current solution is this grouping idea. 
The problem is Even if I manually assign my objects a key, the database ignores this and assigns its own key.

For example:

```
        Question newquestion = new Question()
        newquestion.ID = 1001;
        newquestion.QuestionDescription = "...";

        db.questionDataBase.Add(newquestion);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

When this item is listed in my index.cshtml it has an index of 1, or 2, or 3 (and so on depending on the time it was added). My understanding of databases is not great so I don't know if I'm missing something obvious. Is there anyway for me to change this key id to something I have chosen?

I am hesistant to simply add another attribute, for example

```
        public int QuestionGroupID {get;set;}
```

to do the grouping with, because I have no idea how to search a database for an attribute that is not its key.

So is there a way to assign a custom key value to a database object? Does this just not make sense? I don't know if doing something like this even possible or has my brain has finally broken.

Comment: Unclear why you think you would need that. You should have a table for `Quiz` and a separate table for 'Questions' that has an auto-incremented ID field plus a field for `QuizID` which is the foreign key to the `Quiz` table

Comment: so store the questions as a database of tables? you think that would work? Because man I'll try it. As for why I was doing it this way, I'm just coming up with solutions based on what I know (which is not much). and So far all my attempts to store things like lists (and I assumed tables too) in databases have ended in failure.

Comment: No idea what you mean by _database of tables_? If you do not understand what a relational database is, I can only recommend you buy yourself a good book.

Comment: well how do I store the data from the tables so that it isnt wiped the moment I restart my application? I've never worked with tables so I assumed I was going to store it like an object in its own database.

Comment: What do you mean _wiped the moment I restart my application_? Its a database! The data is not deleted unless you specifically delete it.

Comment: I'm going to read up on this topic more so I can better understand your suggestion.